# idiomatic use case for func which returns a func

Tags: clojure

```
(defn sort-map-by-value
  "Given a map return a sorted map, in which the sort is done on the map's values, instead of keys.
   Takes a function as an input, which will be used  for sorting"
  [cf kf]
  (fn [m]
    (->> m
         map-invert
         (into (sorted-map-by #(cf (kf %1) (kf %2))))
         map-invert)))

(defn date-time-comparator
  "Predicate function for comparing two date-time's"
  [time1 time2]
  (before? time1 time2))

(defn get-time-value
  "Function for extracting the date-time from the value of the given map."
  [v]
  (-> v first :time))

(def sort-map-by-date (sort-map-by-value date-time-comparator get-time-value))

(sort-map-by-date {"3-19-2013" [{:time (date-time 2013 3 19 12 14 45)}]
                         "3-9-2013" [{:time (date-time 2013 3 9 16 46 49)}]
                         "2-25-2013" [{:time (date-time 2013 2 25 2 38 15)}]
                         "3-14-2013" [{:time (date-time 2013 3 14 7 19 23)}]
                         "2-8-2013" [{:time (date-time 2013 2 8 12 44 47)}]
                         })
```

I am trying to understand what is the idiomatic pattern for using higher-order-functions. Specifically for the functions that return functions. The first function sort-map-by-value, takes 2 fns as parameter and returns a function which takes a map as a parameter.

The above function could as well take all three, the 2 funcs and the map as a parameter. So there is no need to create a function which would return another func in this case. What would be a case where it would be needed. Or in other words what is the idiomatic pattern for introducing a function which returns a function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example shown could have been achieved using partial function application in case the function took the map also as parameter.

Basically, function returning a function is a specific case of partial application i.e you do not pass all the params to a function and in return you get a function which will take remaining params and execute the original function. I personally like to use partial application using `partial` or using anonymous functions to create partial functions (ex: `#(map inc %)`).

Why we need them? For one things, they act as glue when you program using function composition. For ex:

You want to write a function that increment each number in a vector and then reverse it.

You can write it without function composition:

```
(defn foo [v]
   (reverse (map inc v)))
```

Using function composition:

```
(def foo (comp reverse (partial map inc)))
```

This may not be the best example but I hope you get the idea.

Another example could be wrapper functions. They take input as a function and return another function (which takes same number of params as the original one) and do something before or after executing the original function (ex: Ring middleware)

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the previous response about `partial`.  And then there's `comp` which takes multiple fn's as input and returns the composition of them as output.

Here's an example that might help, although the output isn't quite a fn.  I wanted to have background threads repeatedly executing some tasks in regular intervals.  Each background thread executes one specific task, but the task differs from one thread to the next.  So it made sense to have a HOF that takes a fn representing the task to repeat and returns a Thread, where the Thread is created that performs the input fn incessantly.  The input fn is made to execute non-stop inside the Thread by being wrapped within a `repeatedly` form.

`partial` is the most likely way in which a HOF where the input and output are both a single fn each.  The example I gave is what happens when the input fn is needed only for its side effects, so there's no point for the HOF's output to be a fn, if there the HOF has an output at all.